# Muawiyah ibn Abi Sufyan status

Tags: halal-haram, sunni, khilafah, ahl-ul-bayt

Why has Muawiyah ibn Abi Sufyan who clearly did not follow the path of Rasulullah and the 4 rightly guided Caliphs in his reign, did many Haram things openly and named his successor his son Yazid unlawfully (which later resulted in the murder of Ahl ul Bayt and the Battle of Harra in Madinah) find a high status in the Sunni school of thought. Are most people ignorant of his doings or they think that he was forgiven?

Comment: What do you mean by "high status in the Sunni school of thought"? As far as I know, Sunnis have never considered Muawiyah's reign *rashid*.

Comment: I know most Sunnis still think that he is innocent because he is a Sahabi. That's why they call him Radiyallahu anhu.

Comment: @AbdiBokhar Why do you think ***most*** sunni Muslims think him an "innocent" sahabi ? Do you have any references or statistics showing this ?